# Проблема с установкой glassfish на win10

Tags: java, glassfish

запускаю домейн -получаю
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0

перелопатил весь интернет ,пишут надо удалить  MaxPermSize ,которая находится в файле idea64.exe.vmoptions
но у меня там такой строки нет 
вот все что там есть

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

помогите кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish 5 не поддерживает версии Java позднее 8-й.

Comment: все прекрасно поддерживается ,нужно лишь удалить MaxPermSize,ну и java у меня 1.8 ,да и фиш я ставлю 4й

Comment: Надо разработчикам сообщить, а то у них в compatibility написано обратное.