# Где искать MaxPermSize?

Tags: java, glassfish

хочу поставить гласфиш на вин10,понятное дело вылетает предупредение
permsize=192,эта опция была убрана в 8й яве и бла бла бла.
решение этой проблемы гугол озвучивает как удаление этой опции из файлов конфигурации,но почему то никто не сказал где эта опция физически находится ,чтобы зайти и удалить.
некоторые пишут что она находится в файле vmoptions и vm64options,но у меня там нет такой строчки.подскажите кто сталкивался где искать и где копать.

Comment: Вот дока. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gepzd/index.html

Comment: https://habr.com/post/169869/ вроде уже не требуется устанавливать permsize, теперь это metaspace и по дефолту может сама занимать столько памяти сколько доступно в системе.

Comment: talex,прежде чем сервер администрировать его нужно запустить,а я не могу ,так как получаю warning  что функция permsize was removed and not support при команде start-domain

Comment: александр не требуется,но чтобы запустить сервер нужно эту опцию удалить,а вот где она находится непонятно,откуда то же warninig вылазит

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с установкой glassfish на win10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927150/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-glassfish-%d0%bd%d0%b0-win10)